# Rails & Apartment: switching tenant based on cookie or domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm working on setting up a multi-tenant app using the [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/) gem and Rails 4.1.

My approach is that the administrative interface will be hosted on a single domain and then serve up tenant-specific data on custom domains. Administrative users will be able to belong to multiple tenants and have the ability to switch between tenants in the administrative interface without switching domains.

Using Apartment, I have been able to switch between tenants using a session cookie without any problem. Here's my code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_tenant

  private 

  def check_tenant
    if session[:current_tenant] and Apartment::Tenant.current_tenant != session[:current_tenant]
      Apartment::Tenant.switch(session[:current_tenant])
    elsif !session[:current_tenant]
      Apartment::Tenant.switch() # Revert to the primary tenant
    end
  end
end
```

The difficulty I'm running into is that Apartment provides domain-name based switching at the middleware level, and I'd like to keep it that way as I assume the middleware is faster than using a before_filter. I see how to implement a generic middleware to switch tenants based upon the request, but I can't seem to access and decrypt the session store in the proc passed to the middleware.

Since using a session store seems to make sense for the administrative interface, do you have any suggestions for accessing the session store at the middleware level or some alternative to bring these two directions together?

Or am I just worrying too much about keeping the tenant switching at the middleware level?

Comment: Follow up on this: Since Apartment+Postgres switches schemas entirely when changing tenants, I decided to use [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant). While this doesn't work in a middleware, there is no need for shared data duplication.

Comment: are you using devise? how do you set session[:current_tenant]?

Comment: @MartinVerdejo Yup, using Devise. I've got a `before_filter` function that checks for a current tenant for the authorized user. If the session doesn't have a :current_tenant key, it picks and sets the current tenant based on what the user has access to. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/deep-spaced/5a8d86cf144ac916aab074536a8690d7). Hope it helps!

Comment: @AndrewAnderson cheers for posting the gist. What if I create a current_tenant session cookie from the client side - then won't I be able to access a different tenant simply by changing the tenant id - if so is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I wrote something for this project that would check for valid access before actually allowing the user to access another tenant. Something like:

`set_tenant(Tenant.find(session[:current_tenant])) if current_user.tenants.includes? session[:current_tenant]`